# TypeValue's getValue returns COMPLEX_RADIX_0p23 instead of a reference

Tags: android, typedreference

I'm using this code to change a view's background whether if it is a colour or a drawable.

```
static void backgroundChangerCompat(Resources resources, int rId, View view) {
        TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
        resources.getValue(rId,value,true);
        if(value.type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && value.type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources,rId,null));
        }
        else if(value.type == TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE) {
            view.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources,rId,null));
        }
    }
```

If I supplied it with a reference i.e a drawable xml, the `value` resolves to a `COMPLEX_RADIX_0p32` which is 0x3. Why is that?

Comment: any reason for not using simple `Resources#getDrawable` method? (it returns `ColorDrawable` if resId points to a static color)

Comment: @pskink Dang it. Haven't browsed enough to notice ResourcesCompat has getDrawable too.

Comment: hmmm, you did not notice that ResourcesCompat has getDrawable? you are using `ResourcesCompat.getDrawable` in your code...

Comment: @pskink didn't noticed that getDrawable takes colours too I mean.